# Computation of: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)^n+\ldots+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)^n\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, summation, solution-verification

> Evaluate:
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)^n+\ldots+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)^n\right)\;n\in\mathbb N$$

My attempt:

Using the manual limit:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+1}\right)^n+\ldots+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)^n\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+i}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^2+i}}\cdot\frac{1}{n(n^2+i)}\right)=0$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Is the log to the power of $n$, or is the argument of the log to the power of $n$?

Comment: in your notation $\ln \alpha^n$ do you mean $\left(\ln \alpha\right)^n$ or $\ln \left(\alpha^n\right) = n \ln \alpha$?

Comment: @gt6989b, I mean $\ln(\alpha^n)=n\ln\alpha$.

Comment: Your expression for the summand is not correct; the $n$ in the denominator of the second term should be in the numerator. Moreover, because the number of terms in the sum also increases with $n$, you can't conclude as you did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{n^{2}+k}\right)^{n}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^{2}+k}\right)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(\frac{n^{2}+n+1}{n^{2}+1}\right)=\color{red}{\boxed {1}}$$

Comment: +1, telescoping product, very clever!

Answer (score 6):

You can squeeze it as follows:

$$n\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)\leq n\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+k}\right)\leq n\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Hence,
$$\underbrace{n^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)}_{\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1}\leq n\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+k}\right)\leq \underbrace{n^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}_{\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1}$$